# Kafka read a batch of messages again and again

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am doing load testing of some service, and so I want to process a batch of 100-200 messages repeatedly for a period of 3-4 days. How should I do it?

Comment: I suspect you need to re-add those messages repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see you have two options. The first option is you can never commit any offset and use a clever combination of `fetch.max.bytes` and other related properties to get all the messages in one go. The other option which I would recommend is that you use `endOffsets()` to get the last offsets of all the partitions and then loop over all of them after every message to check if all the current offsets match the ending offsets. If all are a match, you have reached the end. Then you use `seekToBeginning()` to go back to the beginning.